# angularjs- data binding issue in textareas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, data-binding, 2-way-object-databinding

I have built a timeline using angular js. Timeline shows post from users and other people can add comment for it. For that, I have provided a textarea.
 Setup is simple. i use ng-repeat to show timeline post (which can always be more than one) and as users can comment on each post, textarea is included along with it (like facebook timeline)

So, when I ng-repeat the content, textarea also gets repeated. That is exactly what I need.

But, data-binding is done. So when I type on a textarea, all textarea reflects it. It's like type on one comment textarea, all text-area will show being typed.

How  can I avoid that? I'm new to angularJS

This is my sample code:

```
        <li class="media post" ng-repeat="post in vm.posts">
            <div class="post-main">
              this is a static post
            </div>

                <div class="media comment-textarea">

                    <div class="media-body">
                        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Type here..." rows="1" ng-model="vm.comment.content"></textarea>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary " ng-click="vm.addComment(post,vm.currentComment.content)">
                            <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
                        </a>    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using same `model` value for all timelines, instead I'd suggest you to put `comment` model inside post object only. Make sure you have added comment property to each `post` record.

```
<li class="media post" ng-repeat="post in vm.posts">
    <div class="post-main">
      this is a static post
    </div>

        <div class="media comment-textarea">

            <div class="media-body">
                <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Type here..." rows="1" 
                   ng-model="post.comment.content"></textarea>
                <a class="btn btn-primary " ng-click="vm.addComment(post,post.comment.content)">
                    <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
                </a>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Ok, let me try this. @Pankaj Parkar

Answer (score 1):

you are adding **textarea** with the **ng-repeat** and that why same model **vm.comment.content** is getting attached with all, this is why you are seeing the issue of write in one **textarea** and it displays on all.

you should have a **comment** property  in each object of the array **vm.posts** and you can then bind it to the text area with **ng-model="post.comment"**

in controller

```
$scope.posts = [{comment:""}];
```

in view.

```
    <li class="media post" ng-repeat="post in vm.posts">
        <div class="post-main">
          this is a static post
        </div>

            <div class="media comment-textarea">

                <div class="media-body">
                    <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Type here..." rows="1" ng-model="vm.comment"></textarea>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary " ng-click="vm.addComment(post)">
                        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
                    </a>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: How to avoid that? I have to save these comments to database as well. @Deep

Comment: @SajeevC : i proposed a solution above, using that you will be able to save  the entire data with Posts array

Comment: Thanks, Deep! @Deep